# Python and Win32com module issue with querying SQL Database rows

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, win32com

My goal is to display SQL queries via the Python console using the Win32com module. I am able to use a comobject to access and successfully display the fields of a SQL query however when i try to display rows i am falling into Exceptions.

##### Background

I have used PYODBC which works great however there is a limitation based off what SQL providers are installed and whether TLS 1.2 is enforced. The software sometimes is installed to an external SQL server and therefore no provider on the software's server that can always establish a connection. This is why i am now using the kernal of the software via com objects to access the DB as this circumvents the pitfalls of the provider needing to be installed or the latest Windows update to allow TLS 1.2 connections etc.

Win32com Code that works for me using Fields

```py
import win32com.client
import win32com

"""Connection"""
objprox = win32com.client.Dispatch("****.DbObjectProxy") #Blanked out for security of Software


"""Set Query"""
sql1 = "select * from ServiceConsumer_t"
dbq1 = objprox.DoDatabaseQuery(sql1)

dbq1.Open(sql1)


"""Specify & Print result"""
while not dbq1.EOF:
        col1 = dbq1.Fields("ID").Value
        dbq1.MoveNext()
        print(col1)

"""Close Session"""
dbq1.Close()
```

Output of the above is:

```
{9CAFD41E-D322-4234-BF80-CF6E11A724A0}
{CE4AAE72-0889-41E8-BDB2-ED96696DDB91}
{DC18008F-2C84-4EB4-BCCB-D94FF96E0564}
{1AAB143C-8393-4C1E-BE94-7AB44788D4E4}
```

This is correct as I am specifying the ID column to output and using `MoveNext()` to iterate. This shows I am close to my goal, however, the below code for displaying the rows never appears to work, I am now lost on why?

Win32com Code that does not work for me to display rows:

```py
import win32com.client
import win32com

"""Connection"""
objprox = win32com.client.Dispatch("*****.DbObjectProxy") #Blanked out for security of Software

"""Set Query"""
sql2 = "select * from ServiceConsumer_t"
dbq2 = objprox.DoDatabaseQuery(sql2)

dbq2.Open(sql2)

"""Specify & Print result"""
while not dbq2.EOF:
        dbq2.MoveFirst()
        res = dbq2.GetRows()
        dbq2.MoveNext()
        print(res)

"""Close Session"""
dbq2.Close()
```

From this, I simply get the exception that the object `GetRows` has no attribute. Looking online there is very little surrounding this. Please can you suggest why the code is not working for displaying all row results? Ideally, I would like the column names displayed too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your COM object aligns to the ADODB object, [**`GetRows`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/getrows-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver16) does the following:

> Retrieves multiple records of a Recordset object into an array.

In Python, this array or multidimensional object translates as a nested tuple without metadata like columns names:

```py
rst.MoveFirst()
res = rst.GetRows()   # TUPLE OF TUPLES

# LOOP THROUGH ROWS
for i in range(len(res)):
    # LOOP THROUGH COLUMNS
    for j in range(len(res[i])):        
        print(res[i][j])
```

ADODB example:

```py
import win32com.client

# OPEN SQL SERVER DATABASE CONNECTION
conn = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open(
    "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
    f"Server=myServer;Database=myDatabase;"
    "Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
)

# OPEN RECORDSET
rst = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("ADODB.Recordset")
rst.Open("SELECT * FROM myTable", conn)

rst.MoveFirst()
res = rst.GetRows()

# LOOP THROUGH ROWS
for i in range(len(res)):
    # LOOP THROUGH COLUMNS
    for j in range(len(res[i])):        
        print(res[i][j])
        
# CLOSE AND RELEASE OBJECTS
rst.Close(); conn.Close()
rst = None; conn = None
del rst; del conn
```

Comment: Thank you that worked a lot better than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to this is I added each column manually to create the full row output like below:

```py
col1 = dbq1.Fields("ID").Value
col2 = dbq1.Fields("Name").Value
col3 = dbq1.Fields("Login").Value
col4 = dbq1.Fields("Email").Value
print(str(col1) + " " + str(col2) + " " str(col3) + " " str(col4))
```